# Best way to move the block of code that validates input variables into another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

I have a code like this:

```
function doSomething (inputVar, callback) {
  // Input variables validation
  if (inputVar === 'malformed input') {
    callback(new Error('malformed input'))
    return // prevent the rest of the function from being executed
  }

  console.log("You shouldn't see this message when something goes wrong with the validation.")
  // do other operations
  callback(null)
}
```

What's the best way to move the code that validates input variables into another function so that `doSomething()` looks cleaner and more elegant?

The `return` in the following code doesn't prevent `console.log('You shouldn\'t see this message when something goes wrong with the validation.')` from being executed. I cannot wrap the validation code in this way.

```
function inputValidation (inputVar, callback) {
  if (inputVar === 'malformed input') {
    callback(new Error('malformed input'))
    return // This line doesn't prevent the rest of the `doSomething` from being executed
  }
}

function doSomething (inputVar, callback) {
  // Input variables validation
  inputValidation(inputVar, callback)

  console.log("You shouldn't see this message when something goes wrong with the validation.")
  // do other operations
  callback(null)
}
```

Comment: make the `inputValidation` function return `true` or `false`, call it with the input and check the result. Alternatively, make it throw an exception but that's not usually clean - it essentially falls into leveraging exceptions as flow control and that's generally a bad idea. It can still work in some circumstances but you'd be better off with a boolean.

Comment: Why are you using a `callback`? There's nothing asynchronous in your code, is there?

Comment: I have other asynchronous operations in the function. I didn't write them in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To further elaborate on the comment by @vlaz by returning a value from the validator you can then decide what to do. I dont know exactly how your app is structured or what it does but in general i try and make functions have one purpose, in this case validation is a process of determining if data is valid, calling a callback is not part of that purpose. So maybe a refactoring you could perform is:

```
function isInputValid(inputVar) {
  // perform complex validation logic
  const isValid = inputVar === 'malformed input'
  return isValid
}

function doSomething(inputVar, callback) {
  if(!isInputValid(inputVar)) {
    callback(new Error('malformed input'))
    return
  }

  console.log("Input valid")
  // do other operations
  callback(null)
}

doSomething("foobar", msg => {console.log(`logging callback ${msg}`)})
doSomething("malformed input", msg => {console.log(`logging callback ${msg}`)})
```

This looks a bit silly for a simple example like this but when input validation becomes more and more complex you can move this validation to a separate file and test the validation logic independently of the doSomething logic.

I would also move the operations refered to by `// do other operations` to another function. Again this will aid in both readability and testability.